# How to bind the distance between two Markers to my polyline?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-api-2, google-polyline

First of all I apologise for my poor English.

I currently working on an android-app and I am using the google api v2. I have got 2 Markers on my google map and calculate the distance between them, with the .distancebetween method. Then I draw a Polyline between the markers.

Now i want to bind the distance to my Polyline. The distance should be under the polyline and if i move a marker the distance should still under the polyline.

Comment: Do you have a problem in calculating length of tracking polyline? Or don't know how to draw a text to make it always be under the polyline?

Comment: The Problem is to draw a text to make it always be under the polyline. It should look something like that: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3583/tkka8iyx_png.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy to do, but certainly possible.

Here are the steps:

- calculate center of each line
- for that center latitude, calculate point that is 50dp below it (using `Projection`)
- put a marker on that position
- set marker icon to `Bitmap` with text
- update markers position when you get calls to `OnCameraChangeListener.onCameraChange` or in `Handler`'s `Runnable` posted every few milliseconds

Comment: Thanks for the helpfull answer. About the first step:"calculate center of each line". How can i calculate the Lat and Lng points for the center??

Answer (score -1):

This method may help you to find the distance, it finds the distance between the starting points LatLng and ends point LatLng

```
public double CalculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
    int Radius=6371;//radius of earth in Km         
    double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
    double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
    double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
    double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    double valueResult= Radius*c;
    double km=valueResult/1;
    DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
    int kmInDec =  Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
    double meter=valueResult%1000;
    int  meterInDec= Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
    Log.i("Radius Value",""+valueResult+"   KM  "+kmInDec+" Meter   "+meterInDec);

    return Radius * c;
}
```

you can also try this :

```
Location locationA = new Location("location A");  

locationA.setLatitude(locationA.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);  
locationA.setLongitude(locationA.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);  

Location locationB = new Location("location B");  

locationB.setLatitude(locationB.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);  
locationB.setLongitude(locationB.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);  

double distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

Comment: Location.distanceTo() calculates the closest distance on standard WGS84 ellipsoid, so it will be more accurate than your first piece of code. But for distances less than 500 km it doesn't matter. Second. Why you divide coordinates by 1e6? Third. It calculates the closest distance between 2 points, not by polyline...